# build openSMILE library in ubuntu clock_gettime error

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I am trying to build the openSMILE library on Ubuntu including the Portaudio plugin. Running the provided build script seems fine until the line:
make -j8 make install
where I get the error clock_gettime unresolved.
Anyone encountered the same issue and found out hoe to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the man page for `clock_gettime` (run `man clock_gettime`) you'll see:

> Link with -lrt (only for glibc versions before 2.17).

So, I suggest you add `-lrt` to your link line (`rt` is the realtime library).